# Special content in section heading

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to set an article using the skak chess package and include notation in a section heading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{skak}
\begin{document}
    \section{Open Games (\newgame\mainline{1.e4 e5})}
\end{document}
```

This gives a long list of errors, starting with `Undefined control sequence. ...on{Open Games (\newgame\mainline{1.e4 e5})}`

I know special rules apply in headings but I don't understand them -- how do I get the notation into the section heading? (I know in this case I don't need skak because the resulting notation just looks like the plain text, but that won't always be the case, sometimes  it will involve the symbols for the chess pieces. And skak's checking of the moves for validity is useful too -- the first time I typed it I typed 1.e4 44.)

Edit - based on the answer by DG', my new MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Group}
    \section{Open Games (\protect\newchessgame\mainline{1.e4 e5})}
    \subsection{Centre Game}
    (\newchessgame\mainline{1.e4 e5 2.d4})
    
    \newchessgame\styleC\mainline{1.e4 e5 2.d4 exd4 3.Qxd4 Nc6 4.Qe3     Nf6\wbetter}\storegame{centregame1}
    
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \mainline{5.e5 Ng4 6.Qe4}
        \mainline{6...d5 7.exd6 Be6 8.dxc7 Qd1+ 9.Kxd1 Nxf2 10.Ke1     Nxe4}
        \item \restoregame{centregame1}\mainline{5.Nc3 Bb4 6.Bd2 O-O 7.O-O-O Re8 8.Bc4}\storegame{centregame2}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{Position after White's 8\textsuperscript{th} Move}
        \chessboard
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \caption{Position after White's 13\textsuperscript{th} Move}
        \chessboard
    \end{figure}

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The first few errors this gives are:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \end{document}
                   
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \end{document}
                   
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \end{document}
                   
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! Missing \endgroup inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \endgroup 
l.32 \end{document}
                   
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 \end{document}
```

If I move the chess moves from the heading the problem goes away - though in fairness, if I change almost anything else, including removing some of the lorem ipsum text, the problem still goes away, so I'm no longer sure that's where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xskak` instead of `skak` and protecting the commands in `\section` works in this case. But I have no idea, if it works with more complex games.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\begin{document}
    \section{Open Games (\protect\newgame\mainline{1.e4 e5})}
    \section{Open Games 2 (\protect\newgame\mainline{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6})}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `hyperref`, you might want to write a wrapper like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand\GameLine[1]{%
    \texorpdfstring{\newgame\mainline{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \section{Open Games (\GameLine{1.e4 e5})}
    \section{Open Games 2 (\GameLine{1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 Nf6})}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That only <em>appears</em> to work. I tried it and all seemed well in the heading, but I got apparent random errors all through the rest of the document. When I checked the log, it turned out that it had caused a runaway argument error and Latex couldn't recover properly.

Comment: Does this happen with the MWE or are you using other themes? Does the error occur with your code and `xskak` without the game in the section?

Comment: Hmm. No, not with the MWE. That means I need to make a new MWE - which is going to be a challenge, as adding or removing single words in plain text seems to change the behaviour. Watch this space...

Comment: Meanwhile, I'll give you the answer credit, because you did answer the issue with my MWE!

Comment: Oops - too late. I'm not even sure how to phrase the new problem as a question, as I'm no longer sure where the issue is!